# Смена класса на ссылке и вызов fancybox происходят одновременно, как разделить события?

Tags: jquery, fancybox, toggle

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function () {
      jQuery('.js-page-lightbox').on('click', function() {

     jQuery('.js-page-lightbox').addClass('bg-loading');

        jQuery('.js-page-lightbox').fancybox({
            maxWidth   : 800,
            minWidth   : 600,
            fitToView  : true,
            autoSize   : true,
            title      : false,
            padding    : 40,
            content:   jQuery('#interstitial').show(),

           beforeShow: function(){
               jQuery('.js-page-lightbox').addClass('bg-loading');
           },


           afterClose : function(){
           jQuery('.js-page-lightbox').removeClass('bg-loading')
           }
        });
    });});
```

Мне нужно добавлять класс на кнопку по клику до того как загрузится fancybox.  А выходит, что они срабатывают одновременно. Функция beforeShow или beforeLoad срабатывают у fancybox тоже одновременно. Подскажите, какое может быть решение. Благодарюю

Answer (score 0):

Ссылка должны быть вида:

```
<a href="#lightbox" class="fancybox js-page-lightbox">Ccылка<a>
```

Лайтбокс должен быть спрятан изначально:

```
<div id="lightbox" style="display:none">fancybox content</div>
```

jQuery('.js-page-lightbox').fancybox(); - так фэнсибокс **инициализируется** на ссылке после того, как ссылка отрисована в документе!
Это значит, что сначала мы должны сделать ссылку, которая **указывает** атрибутом "**href**" или "rel"/"data-rel" на заранее спрятанный элемент-лайтбокс.
Чтобы открыть лайтбокс програмно, обычно пишется код, который кликает эту ссылку:

```
$(".fancybox.js-page-lightbox").click();
```

По умолчанию для анимации подгрузки изображений в фэнсибоксе вешается прелоадер:

```
#fancybox-loading div {
    width: 44px;
    height: 44px;
    background: url('fancybox_loading.gif') center center no-repeat;
}
```

Вы можете заменить гифку fancybox_loading.gif в библиотеке на свою или переписать соответствующие стили.

Comment: у меня контент fancybox задается  через content:   jQuery('#interstitial').show(), и вы правы, мне действительно нужно вызвать прелоадер, но он не показывается. Только принудительно вот так jQuery.fancybox.showLoading(); - но тоже срабатывает уже с открытием fancybox.

Comment: Вы не правы, контент не задается .show(). jQuery show.() только '#interstitial' делает видимым с помощью атрибута style="display:block".
Вам не нужно делать самим jQuery('#interstitial').show().
Сначала ссылку на ваш лайтбокс <a href='#interstitial" class="fancybox">Открыть лайтбокс</a>
А потом повесив на неё fansybox вот так:
$("fancybox").fancybox(); 
вы решите все свои задачи, а лайтбокс будет открываться по клику на эту ссылочку мышкой или программно:  $("fancybox").click();

Comment: Благодарю! Меняю логику, но  href - у меня записан через cms, пробую задать через js вот так jQuery('.js-page-lightbox').attr("href", "#interstitial"); но прелоадера нет, не появляется в коде блок с id fancybox-loading. Как его вызвать принудительно до появления fancybox?

Comment: Не совсем понимаю, почему не срабатывает нативный прелодер? Fancybox срабатывает а внутри пусто? По умолчанию, если картинка/видео долго грузится, фэнсибокс открывается, но показывает прелодер - крохотный анимированный кружок. Какая у вас версия фэнсибокса? Или вы снова хотите свою логику работы плагина?

Comment: версия 2.1.5. Он долго грузится без кружочка (

Comment: откройте консоль браузера нажав F12 и посмотрите красные сообщения. Может быть нету fancybox_loading.gif? В разных версиях может быть по-разному, в  2.1.5 прелодер должен лежать в одной папке с jquery.fancybox.css, там же и все остальные картинки-ассеты